# How to use VFP instructions in Arm v8 architecture (Cortex-A53)

Tags: c, gcc, arm, fpu

with my poor knowledge, It may be weird to say "I want to check the assembly code because I wonder if the FPU in processor is enabled with my C code."

Actually I have things like floating point operation that be done with Xilinx Zynq Ultrascale+ board.
and I found it has Cortex-A53 processor in APU, and it also has FPU in it.
so, I want to enable FPU to use for floating point operation.

First, I have to check if the FPU in Cortex-A53 is enabled, but I just found that aarch64 compiles the code with FPU with no gcc compile options, just by default.

so I just write the C code(file name is "test.c") and compile the code with the command line "gcc -S test.c" to get the assembly code(I don't know exactly what the assembly code means)

because I read that the FPU in Cortex-A53 supports VFP instructions, like VADD, VDIV, VMLS..whatever with 'V~~'

but I couldn't find the VFP instructions
I just want to know what kind of code use VFP instructions in C.
want to get the explicit examples like "you should just write and complie the code like float a = 1.11; a+3.14~~ then, you can see the VFP instructions in assembly code with that"

Which code in C I can use to see VFP instructions in assembly?

and just one more thing..
Is it a right way I can check the FPU is enabled?
If it is wrong, how can I enable FPU in Cortex-A53 and How can I check if it is enabled? How can I run the codes with FPU?

Comment: Since you tagged C++, look at the `g++` manual to find the parameter that tells `g++` to compile for a Cortex-A53 or at least an ARM V8 architecture.  You may need to tell `g++`, via parameters, that you want to use the FPU.  Remember: use `g++` for C++ and `gcc` for the C language.

Comment: Type into your favorite search engine, "ARM ARM Cortex-A53" or "ARM reference manual Cortex-A53".  The document should tell you how to detect if an FPU is connected and how to tell that it is awake (enabled).

Comment: Printing the assembly language listing will show the VFP instructions, *if the compiler generated them*.  You may have to use a `#pragma` or command line parameter to force `g++` to use the VFP instructions.

Comment: how to use to force gcc, I want to compile C code, to use VFP, what command I should use to do it? I want to know explicit code or command. and I already read reference manual.

Comment: You may want to edit your language tags and only mention that you are programming in C.  The C++ is a different language, for example, C++ allows function and operator overloading.

Comment: You will need to research parameters of `gcc` to figure out how to tell `gcc` to compile for ARM Cortex-A53 with FPU enabled.  Sorry, but I don't memorize all of the available command line parameters for `gcc`.

Comment: Ok I just delete c++ tag and thank you that I got it..with no offense. I have just few knowledge about that. so it may be frustrating, I totally don't know about it. assembly code that I made with my code don't have VFP instructions but subp, movb, addq things in it. my code is just with codes like "float a=1.13~~". I think it use just ordinary instructions, not VFP instructions. what code should I write and compile to use VFP instructions?

Comment: I think I have to search more for it...I've searched a lot though. thank you, but if anybody that knows about it is here, please make me know

Comment: Again, you need to tell the compiler to emit VFP instructions; this is done by telling the gcc compiler (via command line parameters) that you have a FPU and to force the compiler to emit VFP instructions.  Search and research the gcc command line parameters.  We did this for a while until we switched to the IAR compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a long description, but still lack a lot of information.

Xilinx Zynq Ultrascale+ is ARMv8 core which could run in 32bit mode or 64bit mode. So there are two type of toolchain for each mode, there are some differents in compilation flags.

For 32b mode `-mfpu=neon` should do, refer [ARM options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Options.html)

For 64b mode 'advanced simd' is mandatory, so no command line option is needed. Still you might want to enable auto vectorization optimisations with `-O3` or `-O2 -ftree-vectorize`, otherwise compiler might not bother to use simd.

> Is it a right way I can check the FPU is enabled? If it is wrong, how
> can I enable FPU in Cortex-A53 and How can I check if it is enabled?
> How can I run the codes with FPU?

Out of head, there is a bit in some fpu state register that indicates if it's enabled. You did not tell if you work baremetal or under OS. Access to such registers might not be available from 'user mode' when apps run under OS. Simple way is always to run some fpu command like `vadd` inside `asm volatile(...)` for example, if fpu not enabled/supported, you get exception.